# How to delay ActiveRecord MySQL reconnect during a failover

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, high-availability

We have a Rails 3.1.3 app, connecting to MySQL via the mysql2 gem. Standard config. We also have a handful of Resque workers performing background jobs. The DB hostname we point to (in database.yml) is actually a Virtual IP (VIP) that points to either node1 or node2.

Behind the scenes, the two MySQL servers (nodes) are setup in a High Availability configuration. The data folders are replicated via DRBD, with mysqld only running on the "active" node. When the cluster detects that node1 is not available, it starts mysqld on node2 and points the VIP to it.

If you want more details on the specific setup, it's very similar to [this MySQL HA cookbook](http://www.fromdual.ch/mysql-active-passive-fail-over-cluster-with-centos).

**Here's the issue:** When a failover happens, it takes approx 30-60 seconds to complete, during which there is no MySQL server available. Any Resque jobs that are currently running fail badly.

**Here's the question(s):** How can we tell ActiveRecord to reconnect after a delay? Maybe attempt several reconnects with a backoff timer? Or is there a better way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your HA setup is going to cause you infinite amounts of pain in the future. Use database-layer replication instead of block-device-layer replication; [MySQL Proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy) was designed to do this.